# Как прикрепить метод Controller к роуту?

Tags: php, mvc

Всем привет. Начал потихоньку разбиратся с MVC . Создал модель и контроллер , а с роутингом тупо завис. Поставил себе такой роутер https://github.com/klein/klein.php - все работает , а  прикрепить метод контроллера не получается.

index.php

```
 <?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $controller =new ProductController($model);
    $klein = new \Klein\Klein();

    $klein->respond('GET', '/hello-world', function () {
        return 'Hello World!';
    });

    $klein->dispatch();
```

В контроллере есть метод index (его проверил работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации, контроллером является коллбек, указанный третьим параметром в методе Klein::respond. Стоит либо прописать код контроллера в этой функции (как указано в документации), либо передать Ваш метод ProductController::index в качестве коллбека `call_user_func([$controller, 'index'])` (считаю, так себе идея)

Также не очень идея инициализировать контроллер моделью. Лучше создать класс сервиса, в котором накодить бизнес-логику, и передавать его в роутинг (описано на гитхабе в разделе "Lazy services")